# Escaped HTML markup being rendered in dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Tags: html, wordpress, reactjs, gatsby, wp-api

I have a Gatsby + WP API blog setup (with Markdown enabled) and it's working great, except when I'm trying to display HTML markup as code snippets. I'm using escape characters (see below), but for some reason the HTML inside the `<code>`/`<pre>` tags is rendering as actual HTML instead of displaying as an HTML code snippet.

I understand that's what `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is there to do, but I didn't think it would if I'm using the escape character `&lt;`?

Here's the markup inside the WP blog post..

```
<pre class="language-markup"><code>
  &lt;div&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum...&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;
</code></pre>
```

And this is how I'm displaying the entire post content in the react component...

```
<section className="article-body" itemProp="articleBody"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.html }}
/>
```

The `<div>` and `<p>` tags rendering as HTML, instead of displayed as a code snippet..

[image: HTML Markup Rendering inside code tag]

Is there some other way I should be doing this? For the record I also tried this using a 'non-dangerously' method ([react-render-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-render-html)) with the same results.

**-- UPDATE: --**

I was able to display the HTML as a code snippet by replacing the `<code>` tag with `<xmp>`. I know this tag is no longer officially supported, and it's far from elegant, so I think I may try to separate code snippets from the rest of the content as suggested below.

Comment: Seems to work fine in CodeSandbox, can you post your CSS?

Comment: @Colin good point, I'm using Prism for syntax highlighting, removed it and now the div/p tags at least are showing in inspector, but still not showing in code block...instead they're getting rendered as regular HTML. Let me update issue..

Comment: What do you see in the GraphiQL inspector at http://localhost:8000/___graphql while Gatsby is running? Can you add this to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in CodeSandbox, too - working as expected. If you're sure about data (escaping) received from WP API I affraid it's a Gatsby issue. There must be a place where it's modified (unescaped).

If data will be ok and you don't want to make deep ivestigation there could be workaround. Split article body and treat sections separately - texts and code snippets. The second wrap with code literal with sth like this:

```
const CodeBlock = (props) => {
  return <section className="article-code">
    <pre className="language"><code>{`${props.html}`}</code></pre>
  </section>
}
```

Of course remove unused first and last line of original code/snippet block.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, thinking I'm going to have to separate the code snippets from rest of content. For the record I got the HTML displaying correctly by replacing the `<code>` tag with `<xmp>`.

Comment: Separating will give you ability to use some ready syntax highlighter libs/components.

Comment: This would require you to know where each code block is going to be placed inside your article though. I guess it won't work very well in Gatsby. It might in a regular React app.

Comment: In WP content (article) is in one block (even edited with Gutenberg). Separating mixed content into chain/list of 'typed' blocks (or more granulary paragraphs) of course means preserving their order. You should be able to render entire article content/structure (many text and code blocks) exactly like using php templates/themes. I'm pretty sure it's doable in Gatsby ;)